# How to open the default app on a mobile device based on the file extension?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

We are writing a cross platform application in Firemonkey.
One of the features is that the user can download files that are stored on the server.
Therefore we have a REST service the application uses to download the file.

We don't know the file type, it could be pdf, image or a word document, ...
I'm looking for a routine that allows launching the standard app on the mobile device that is capable of opening the document and this for IOS and Android.

Can anybody help me with that?

Thx,

Dominique

Comment: "*We don't know the file type*" - is the REST server not reporting the type of file it is sending?

Comment: Hi Remy, yes, the REST server returns also the filename, so we know the file type, but it can be any type of file. I'm looking for somekind of a routine that will allow IOS or Android to decide which is the most appropriate app to use, something like open with and it presents a choice of available apps to view the file. There seem to be a lot of answers concerning this for Android but not for IOS apparently.

Comment: There is no `Content-Type` being sent along with the filename?  Or, is the `Content-Type` just a general purpose type, like `application/octet-stream`?  I don't know about iOS, but Android certainly does have a way for an `Intent` to request an App Chooser dialog be displayed, but you have to provide the file name+type so the Dialog can filter out apps that don't work with the file.

Comment: The files are coming from a Delphi application written in Unigui. The users upload the files in the backoffice application from their pc. This can be pdf, word, images. We only the the extension as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered many times, but the basics of it on Android goes like this:

```
var
  Data: Jnet_Uri;
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Data := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('file://sdcard/test.jpg'));
  Intent.setDataAndType(Data, StringToJString('image/*'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

You have to adjust the `SetDataAndType` based on the file extension for each filetype you encounter. That would be within a long 'case-like' structure.

I don't know how to do the same thing on iOS.